# Spring AOP : Intercepting spring framework class

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, aop, interception

Can I intercept spring framework class using my custom Aspect like : 
Intercepting all public methods of : org.springframework.integration.mail.Pop3MailReceiver

```
@Aspect
public class Pop3MailReceiverAspect {
@AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(* org.springframework.integration.mail.Pop3MailReceiver.*(..))")
public void getNameAdvice(){
    ........
}
```

Comment: using aspects in programming produces hard-to-test code. Can you tell us, what is the problem you trying to solve, maybe the is better solution for it

Comment: In this case , I wanted to trap the spring poller's success case. Actually